# Cannot read property 'injectReducers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to load reducers in async. I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/eggheadio-projects/egghead-universal-component/tree/master/13-Lazy-Load-Redux-Reducers-with-Code-split-Universal-React-Components-using-onLoad), but for some reason the `store` in the `onLoad` at `react-universal-component` is undefined.

src/routes.js line 5 - 
`{store: undefined, report: undefined}`

I also get an error `Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.` when trying to inject the reducer. When I do it in sync, it seems to load just fine.

Here's a [repo](https://github.com/abarcenas29/ssr-react-boilerplace) to play. Just `yarn run start` to see the error.

Comment: Might it have to do with the async? Maybe it gets to the `onLoad`, before the async process is done, so it ends up being `undefined`.

Comment: @Mr A got any solution?